# HTML, set iframe src as a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, document.write

I would like to display a window in my webpage of another webpage, hopefully via iframe.  I need to set the src as a javascript variable, here is the code:

```
<html>
<head><title>my webpage</title></head>
<SCRIPT language=JavaScript type=text/javascript>
function GoToURL(j) {
var URLis = document.URLframe.Dest.value
document.write("<center><iframe src=\"http://www.example.com\"/ width=1350 height=500     seamless></center>");
    }
</SCRIPT>
<FORM name=URLframe>
<TABLE align=center border=0>

<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD vAlign=center align=middle><BR><INPUT maxLength=50 size=50 
  name=Dest></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD align=middle>
  <P><INPUT onclick=GoToURL(this) type=button value="                       Go to..                                " name="Go to"></P></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></FORM>
</html>
```

I need to set the iframe src to the variable URLis, simply put.  I am somewhat of a newb in both html and javascript, so please keep as simple as possible.  Do you have any suggestions or ideas for a way to set the iframe src as URLis variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Why cant you just target your link to that iframe?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what that means

Comment: You probably mean your question... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var URLis = document.URLframe.Dest.value;
document.write('<center><iframe src="' + URLis + '" width=1350 height=500 seamless></center>');
```