# How do I make iframe get src from js variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if anyone could help me with making a program in HTML that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var iframesite = prompt ('Enter in a site');
        </script>
        <iframe src="?"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

So what would I put in the place of the `"?"` ?  I want it to be javascript inside of the src attribute so that I can put `'https:// ' + iframesite` for a src.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML, set iframe src as a javascript variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654868/html-set-iframe-src-as-a-javascript-variable)

Comment: Another one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000987/dynamically-set-iframe-src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding a Iframe would work. Here is some example code:

```
var iframesite = prompt ('Enter in a site');
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.src = iframesite;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Comment: @PinkTurtle You can get never enough help ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use plain javascript you can achieve this with something like this:

```
var iframesite = prompt ('Enter in a site');
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("src", "https://" + iframesite );
```

Otherwise I would suggest you to have a look at [jquery](http://jquery.com)